# Remove string from Array in Json object looping through documents

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, nosql, ravendb

I have multiple documents in a RavenDB NoSql database. I'm using restful services to post, put and get the Team documents when needed. However, I need to create functionality to type a string and loop through all the documents splicing out that specific string from the document as it goes through each document. My JSON format is as such.

```
{
"Name": " Management Team Lead",
"IsActive": true,
"UserRoleId": "userRoles/DemoSystemAdmin",
"Region": "Europe",
"Country": "Unknown",
"CommitteeType": "Haaa",
"MemberUserIds": [
    "joeBlogs",
    "TomCreen",
    "Herbyvoire",
    "MayJune",
],
"PortfolioIds": [],
"LegalEntityIds": []
```

}

In this case I have to check 40+ plus team documents if a MemberUserId exists in that Team document and if so remove it.
I'm very new to .Net but I imagine what I'll be trying to do is loop "Get" each document, then check to see if the string matches the Json and if it does splice in a blank and "Put" back to database.

How do I go about looping through each document without having to specify the name of each?

Comment: Surely RavenDB allows you to query only the records that contain the value you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RQL, you can do this with the following query:

```
from Users as u
where u.MemberUserIds[] = 'TomCreen'
update {
    u.MemberUserIds = u.MemberUserIds.filter(m => m != 'TomCreen')
}
```

This will both find only the relevant documents and update them.